# Using runningtotal()  inside a  Max()  in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a report using a matrix which have 3 row group and 2 column group. Now I wanted to calculate the sum total of a column based on a row group. I searched for a solution but didn't got one. 
The only solution that I could think of was to use a RunningValue Function

Now my running value column output is like

```
| Original Values || Running Value |
|-----------------||---------------|
|     6676        ||   6777        | 
|.................||---------------|
|     6859        ||   13625       |
|.................||---------------|
|     5320        ||   66830       |
```

Now I want the result 66830 so that i can use it to compute other values
so can anyone please tell me

How to use RunningTotal function inside MAX function

what I am doing is

```
=MAX(runningvalue(Fields!NET.Value,sum,"matrix1_MIX"))
```

but it gives me an error

```
  An error occurred during local report processing.
    The defination of the report'Report1' is invalid.
    The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox106.paragraphs[0]TextRuns[0]' contains an 
aggregate function (or RunningVale or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another 
aggregate functiion (or RunningValue). Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other 
aggregate functions.
```

Is there a workaround to this problem in ssrs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of a RunningValue by sum is the same as the regular SUM of the same value, taken in the scope of the entire group. Try something like this:

```vb
=Sum(Fields!NET.Value, "matrix1_MIX")
```

Think carefully about what you use for the second argument, that's key to getting the figure you need.

Comment: no its not working this way whenever i tried this the total comes right but when i expand the column group the total do not divide but remains the same.

Comment: Did you try fiddling with the scope parameter, narrowing it to the correct group? If you can't get it to work then you should edit your question and add a more complete example of the expected results, currently the sample dataset doesn't contain groups, etc.